# how to add -Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xl-deploy

I Cannot connect to Xebia Deploy server from Jenkins getting below error

```
XL Deploy configuration is not valid! com.xebialabs.deployit.ci.DeployitPluginException: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/xml and type interface java.util.List
```

I got the solution that I have to add **-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false**  to the Java startup commands of Jenkins.

In Jenkins how can I set this value?

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search reveals: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698-How-to-add-Java-arguments-to-Jenkins-